# How to remove suspended IIS application pool

Tags: php, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have a web server **IIS 8.5. OS v: Windows Server 2012**.

When number of Hit increase then huge **php-cgi.exe** open in windows process.But after some time lot of process shows suspended state.

As a result, site down and system make too slow to response. There have a recycling/ restart option in IIS application pool.

But, if i restart the application pool in every minute then current connected users will be unreachable. How we can remove only the suspended process.please check the images.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the problem.

Step1: Create a TaskKill command at your suitable.like:

```
taskkill  /IM "php-cgi.exe" /F  /FI "Username eq Yourusername" /FI "MemUsage lt 300" /T
```

most of the suspended process use below 300k memory usages. [Task Kill detail parameter](http://www.computerhope.com/taskkill.htm)

Step2: create a batch file.like:

```
@echo off
taskkill  /IM "php-cgi.exe" /F  /FI "Username eq Yourusername.com" /FI "MemUsage lt 300" /T
:exit
```

Step3: Run the batch file every 5 min (or your required time) by windows task scheduler.

Go to

> Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Task Scheduler

add the task to task scheduler.[Configure Task Scheduler](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-schedule-batch-file-run-automatically-windows-7)

That's all. You don't find any suspended process into your system.